# Edit the array and save the file as a new php file

Tags: php, arrays, file

There is a file named `default.Db.php` just containing:

```
<?php 
// OLD FILE
function get_DbConfig(){
    $config = array (
                'source'    =>  'array',                            
                'host'      =>  'DATABASE_HOST',
                'port'      =>  'DATABASE_PORT',
                'username'  =>  'DATABASE_USER',
                'password'  =>  'DATABASE_PASSWORD',
                'database'  =>  'DATABASE_NAME'
            );
    return $config;
}
require_once './../Common/php/face.php';
?>
```

What is way to replace `$config` inside `get_dbConfig` with my own array? For example, an array where each key has a specific value. After replacing the values inside this array, I will rename the file to `Db.php`

```
<?php
// NEW FILE
function get_DbConfig(){
    $config = array (
                'source'    =>  'array',                            
                'host'      =>  'localhost',
                'port'      =>  '3306',
                'username'  =>  'foo',
                'password'  =>  'bar',
                'database'  =>  'foobar'
            );
    return $config;
}
require_once __DIR__.'./../Common/php/OperateDB/DbMgrInterface.php';
?>
```

Comment: And why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: @DebosmitRay So, that I could fill this array with my own values that I get at run time.

Comment: normal approach is add variable as function parameter

Comment: you can use array_replace function

Comment: Do you want to change array value dynamically? then just pass value to that index number

Comment: @RahulDambare Could you show me how?

Comment: Is necessary have the code wrapped with function? This is the config so you can use static or constant variable

Comment: @daremachine Yes. All the code has been written like that!

Comment: ok so its basic. Create a file with your configuration code and save it as php easy http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Comment: @daremachine I know. But is there a way, I could edit this file and fill in the values for the array key?

Comment: yes easy .. but you need to write good generator e.g. createConfig(), changeConfig($array) and your generator regenerate your config array and save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do this way. There are better methods to achieve this. However, you could do the following:

```
try {
            // Read the whole file into memory
            $fileStr = file_get_contents('../default.Db.php');
            // Replace each string with a valid value
            $fileStr = str_replace('DATABASE_HOST', HOST, $fileStr);
            $fileStr = str_replace('DATABASE_USER', USER, $fileStr);
            $fileStr = str_replace('DATABASE_PASSWORD', PASSWORD, $fileStr);
            $fileStr = str_replace('DATABASE_NAME', DB_NAME, $fileStr);
            $fileStr = str_replace('DATABASE_PORT', PORT, $fileStr);
            // Write the modified content
            file_put_contents("../default.Db.php", $fileStr);
            // Rename default.Db.php to Db.php
            $isRenamed = rename('../default.Db.php','../Db.php');
            if($isRenamed) {
                require_once './../Db.php';
            }
        }catch(Exception $exc) {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First  you have to  pass argument in your function. after that when you call that function, at that time you have to pass your array  in that  and assign array value with assign variable.

```
    <?php
    function get_DbConfig($configdata){
            $config = array (
                'source'    =>  $configdata ['array'],                            
                'host'      =>  $configdata['DATABASE_HOST'],
                'port'      =>  $configdata['DATABASE_PORT'],
                'username'  =>  $configdata['DATABASE_USER'],
                'password'  =>  $configdata['DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
                'database'  =>  $configdata['DATABASE_NAME']
            );
    return $config;
}
require_once './../Common/php/face.php';
?>
```

Comment: This would mean calling the function every time with a configuration. I want to edit/modify the default.Db.php file, so that when I call `get_DbConfig` it just returns me the values set earlier

Comment: ok so you want to change the array and save the file as php file?

Comment: @daremachine Exactly.

Comment: This is one  time process or Every time you want  to make new file for  that config?  and you want  to change only "array" value  which key is source?

Comment: @viralPathak One time.

Comment: ok,  Try above  code and   and pass your  value  as argument and assign all the value as per your need.....

Comment: try  above code  and pass your value  at one  time  and   it will work  fime